# How to have Kotlin "Listen" when a function finish executing Successfully

Tags: kotlin

This is my first time using Kotlin, I have to write a simple command-line application where it takes a list of user input strings. Valid inputs are only "Apple" or "Orange" and calculate the price (which is 60 cents and 25 cents respectively). I'm having some trouble with the 3rd requirement

*"Build a service that listens for when orders are complete and sends a notification to the customer regarding its status and estimated delivery time. The Mail service subscribes to events from the Orders service and publishes the appropriate event that the customer (you) is able to read from the terminal"*

this is what I have done so far

MainApp.tk

```
import java.util.Scanner
import kotlin.system.exitProcess;
import app.Checkout;
 var shopRunning = true;
var applecount = 0;
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        while (shopRunning) {
      
        println("Welcome to Express Store");
        println("1. Checkout");
        println("2. exit");
        var userOption = 0;
        //request the user to eneter an option
        //if user eneter a options that is not valid it will keep looping til option that is enterd is accepted;
        var userSeletedOption = false;
        val inputScanner = Scanner(System.`in`);
        while (!userSeletedOption) {
            print("Select an Option: ");
            userOption = inputScanner.nextInt();
            //if input entered by the user is not accepted and invaliud message is printed and is promted to enter an option again.
            if (userOption != 1 && userOption != 2) {
                println("Invalid input detected!");
            } else {
                userSeletedOption = true;
            }
        }

        if (userOption == 1) {
            val checkout = Checkout();
            println("We currently have apples and oranges in Stock.")




                var list: MutableList<String> = ArrayList();



                println(list.size);
            var doneAddingToCart = false;
            while(!doneAddingToCart){
                print("enter name of item to be enter or exit to finish adding to the cart: ")
                var item = inputScanner.next();
                if(item.equals("exit")){
                    doneAddingToCart=true;
                }
                else{
                    list.add(item);
                }
            }

            if(checkout.verify(list)){ //checks if list has any item that is not an apple or orange
               println("Thank you for your Pruchse");
                val  cost = checkout.Chasher(list)
                println("You bought: "+ list.toString());
                print("your total is: "+ cost);//returns the total cost
                exitProcess(1);//exits from the application
            }

        } else if (userOption == 2) {
            print("Have a great day.");
            exitProcess(1);
        }
    }
}
```

CheckOut.tk

```
class Checkout {
//checks if the user entered any invaild items
public fun verify (cart: MutableList<String>) : Boolean{
    for(item in cart){
        if(!item.equals("Apple") && !item.equals("Orange")){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public fun Chasher (cart: MutableList<String>) : Double{
    var total = 0.0;


    var orangecount = 0;//step 2 offers
    var applecount = 0;//step 2 offers

    for(item in cart){//step 1 function
        if(item.equals("Apple") || item.equals("apple")){
            applecount+=1;
            total=  total + 0.6;
        }
        if(item.equals("Orange") || item.equals("orange")){
            orangecount +=1;

            total=total +0.25;
        }
    }
    if(orangecount ==3){//buy three for the price of 2.step 2
        println("You qaulidified for our buy 3 oragnes for the price of 2 offer")
        total -=0.25;
    }
    if(applecount ==1){//buy one aple get 1 free. step 2
        println("You buy 1 apple get one free")
        cart.add("Apple");
    }

    return total;
}
}
```

I don't need to send an email just send a message to the command line. Currently, I'm just printing messages (just to see if what I currently have even works). *Yeah, I know there many spelling errors, english and writing was never my strongest subject*

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking, please?  The title asks about ‘listening’ (whatever that is), but the last paragraph talks about ‘sending a message to the command line’ (which would normally just mean `println()` and similar).

Comment: PS. I quote the following line without comment :-)  “[We've found by experience that people who are careless and sloppy writers are usually also careless and sloppy at thinking and coding (often enough to bet on, anyway).](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#writewell)”

Comment: @gidds I also thought that using println() command is what it was asking. Though I'm very unsure. The requirement states in quotes "listens for when orders are complete". I thought to just write a function that just uses some print statements. Then I was thinking maybe I have to use an event listener based on the next line of the requirement "The Mail service subscribes to events from the Orders service and publishes an appropriate event". This is my first time working with kotlin so forgive me I don't know too much.

Comment: `SharedFlow` comes to mind. https://elizarov.medium.com/shared-flows-broadcast-channels-899b675e805c

Comment: This seems more like an analysis or design question than a Kotlin question.

Answer (score 0):

I can only provide three hints that might help you:

1. If you exit your program using `System.exit`, use `0` if the run did not have any problem. (Excerpt from JavaDoc: "The argument serves as a status code; by convention, a nonzero status code indicates abnormal termination.")
2. For checking equality, simply use `==` which corresponds to `equals` in Java. In your special case however, you can use item.equals("apple", ignoreCase=true) or simply `item.equals("apple", true)`.
3. I'm not sure what the author of your task exactly expects as a solution.
   In can imagine you are **expected to use lambdas**.

An example: Your could refactor your Checkout class like that:

```kotlin
class Checkout {
    /**
     * Checks if the given [cart] contains only apples and oranges,
     * and calls [onSuccess].
     * If also other articles are contained, [onSuccess] is not called.
     */
    fun verify(cart: List<String>, onSuccess: (List<String>) -> Unit): Unit {
        for (item in cart) {
            if (!item.equals("apple", true) && !item.equals("Orange", true)) {
                return
            }
        }
        onSuccess(cart)
    }
}
```

And then call

```kotlin
val cart = listOf("Orange", "Apple", "apple", "orange")

Checkout().verify(cart, { cart: List<String> ->
    println("Thanks you for your purchase: $cart")
})
```

or even shorter (curly brackets are outside of parenthesis)

```kotlin
Checkout().verify(cart) { cart: List<String> ->
    println("Thanks you for your purchase: $cart")
}
```

What I did here was to extract what is executed if your validation succeeds:
For that, I used a lambda function that accepts a list of articles/strings `(List<String>)` and returns something I ignore/don't care about `-> Unit`.

The advantage of that approach is that callers of your `verify` method can decide what to do on success at their liking because they can pass a lambda function around like any other variable. Here:

```kotlin
val cart = listOf("Orange", "Apple", "apple", "orange")

val onSuccess = { cart: List<String> ->
    println("Thanks you for your purchase: $cart")
}

Checkout().verify(cart, onSuccess)
```

You could also extend Checkout to allow an observer to register.
I deliberately kept the code very simple. Normally you would allow multiple observers to register, only expose what clients are supposed to see and hide the rest, etc.

```kotlin
class Checkout(
    val onSuccess : (List<String>) -> Unit
) {    

    fun verify(cart: List<String>): Unit {
        for (item in cart) {
            if (!item.equals("apple", true) && !item.equals("Orange", true)) {
                return
            }
        }
        onSuccess(cart)
    }
}
val checkout = Checkout({ cart: List<String> ->
    println("Thanks you for your purchase: $cart")
})
```

and then

```kotlin
val cart = listOf("Orange", "Apple", "apple", "orange")
checkout.verify(cart)
```

Be sure to check out https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/04_functional/01_Higher-Order%20Functions to learn more about lambda / higher-order functions.